# sort feed by engagement count django

Tags: python, django, post, count, feed

I would like to sort my feed containing image posts by the engagement (number_of_dislikes + number_of_likes), so that the most popular post is on top. But I'm pretty unsure of how to do it. Please have a look at what I have so far and help me out.
There are two main problems: one, I have the engagement-post in the html displayed in the same way as the like or dislike, which only reveals the number on click. I tried to change that by just displaying the engagement_count but it only showed the numbers of the posts I´ve clicked on before when the button was still there. How do I display an always counting number of engagement?
secondly, i need to sort the feed by that count...

thanks a lot.

index.html (homepage)

```
{% for post in posts %}

                        <div class="bg-white shadow rounded-md  -mx-2 lg:mx-0">

    
                            <!-- post header-->
                            <div class="flex justify-between items-center px-4 py-3">
                                <div class="flex flex-1 items-center space-x-4">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <div class="bg-gradient-to-tr from-yellow-600 to-pink-600 p-0.5 rounded-full">  
                                            <img src="{% static 'assets/images/avatars/user.png' %}" class="bg-gray-200 border border-white rounded-full w-8 h-8">
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <span class="block capitalize font-semibold "><a href="/profile/{{ post.id }}">@{{ post.id }}  </a></span>
                                </div>
                              <div>
                                <a href="#"> <!-- <i class="icon-feather-more-horizontal text-2xl hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-full p-2 transition -mr-1 "></i> --></a>
                                <div class="bg-white w-56 shadow-md mx-auto p-2 mt-12 rounded-md text-gray-500 hidden text-base border border-gray-100  " <!-- uk-drop="mode: hover;pos: top-right">
                              
        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            {% if post.image %}
    
                            <div uk-lightbox>
                                <a href="{{ post.image.url}}">
                                    <img src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
    
                            <div class="py-3 px-4 space-y-3"> 
                               
                                <div class="flex space-x-4 lg:font-bold">
                                    <a href="/like-post?post_id={{ post.id }}" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                                        <div class="p-2 rounded-full text-black">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="25" height="25" class="">
                                                <path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
                                            </svg>
                                            {% if post.number_of_likes == 0 %}
                                            <p>no likes</p>
                                            {% else%}
                                            <p>liked by {{ post.number_of_likes }} user</p>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </a>

                                    <a href="/dislike-post?post_id={{ post.id }}" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                                        <div class="p-2 rounded-full text-black">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="25" height="25" class="">
                                                <path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
                                            </svg>
                                            {% if post.number_of_dislikes == 0 %}
                                            <p>no dislikes</p>
                                            {% else%}
                                            <p>disliked by {{ post.number_of_dislikes }} user</p>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="/engagement-post?post_id={{ post.id }}" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                                        <div class="p-2 rounded-full text-black">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="25" height="25" class="">
                                                <path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
                                            </svg>
                                            {% if post.engagement_count == 0 %}
                                            <p>nothing happened</p>
                                            {% else%}
                                            <p>{{ post.engagement_count}} </p>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                    </a>


              </div>
    
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('upload', views.upload, name='upload'),
    path('like-post', views.like_post, name='like-post'),
    path('dislike-post', views.dislike_post, name='dislike-post'),
    path('engagement-post', views.engagement_post, name='engagement-post'),
]
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images')
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    number_of_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    number_of_dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    engagement_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)#number_of_dislikes + number_of_likes


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
class LikePost(models.Model):
    post_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
class DislikePost(models.Model):
    post_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username



class FollowersCount(models.Model):
    follower= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user =models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    posts= Post.objects.all()

    feed=[]
    engagement_count_list = [posts,
            Post.objects.annotate(count=Count('engagement_count')).order_by('-count')]

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': posts})

def like_post(request):
    username = request.user.username
    post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    new_like = LikePost.objects.create(post_id=post_id, username=username)
    new_like.save()
    post.number_of_likes = post.number_of_likes+1
    post.save()
    return redirect('/')


def dislike_post(request):
    username = request.user.username
    post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')

    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

    new_dislike = DislikePost.objects.create(post_id=post_id, username=username)
    new_dislike.save()
    post.number_of_dislikes = post.number_of_dislikes+1
    post.save()
    return redirect('/')

def engagement_post(request):
    post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')

    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

    post.engagement_count = post.number_of_likes + post.number_of_dislikes
    post.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to remodel this, to:

```
from django.conf import settings


class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images')
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption


class LikeDislikePost(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    LIKE_DISLIKES = ((1, 'like'), (-1, 'dislike'))
    like_type = models.IntegerField(choices=LIKE_DISLIKES, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

You thus create a like with `like_type = 1` and a dislike with `like_dislike = -1`. The `like` method then thus looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def like_post(request):
    username = request.user.username
    post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
    new_like = LikePost.objects.create(post_id=post_id, user=request.user)
    return redirect('/')
```

Then you sort the `Post`s with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.alias(engagement=Count('likedislikepost')).order_by('-engagement')
```

There is *no* need to store the number of likes and dislikes in the post. This will only make it harder to keep it in sync properly.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with such requests. Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and
> DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls.

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Comment: hi willem, it doesn't work. now i can't like or dislike anything, because it goes to a type error : TypeError at /dislike-post
DislikePost() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'user', Also I´m a little confused how the def index in total looks like...

Comment: @amber: the dislike should be the same as the `dislike`, except that it has a `like_type=-1`. It of course only works with the modeling changes at the top.

Comment: thx for your answer. I´m still confused what the def index should look like adding your solution to sort the posts in the end. atm i have this there: def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.alias(engagement=Count('likedislikepost')).order_by('-engagement')     and then: return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': posts}). --> it's not sorting by engagement yet. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Out of some other reasons I need the interaction stored in each post. But the solution was in the answer before. I mixed that approach with mine.

```
def index(request):
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('interaction_count')
count_posts = Post.objects.count()
return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': posts, 'count_posts':count_posts})



def like_post(request):
post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
new_like = LikePost.objects.create(post_id=post_id)
new_like.save()
post.number_of_likes = post.number_of_likes+1

new_interaction = InteractionPost.objects.create(post_id=post_id)
new_interaction.save()
post.interaction_count = post.interaction_count + 1

post.save()
return redirect('/')


class Post(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
num_post = models.IntegerField(default=0)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=post_images)
caption = models.TextField(max_length=300)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
number_of_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
number_of_dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
interaction_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.caption
```